# Given a BST, and a node in BST, make that node, as new root of the tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Given a `BST`, and a node in `BST`, make that node, as new root of the tree. But still maintain the tree as `BST` after making this node as root.

I tried as follows:
Take given node as root, if its on left of original root then make original root as right child of it and left child of original root as a left child of new root (similarly if new root is on right of original root). Now, there are two cases:

1. If node (new root's position in original structure) is leaf, then no worries at all
2. Problem is when node (new root's position in original structure) is internal node, then what can be done?

Comment: I notice that you *never* replied or accepted any of your questions, may I know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, your algorithm needs perform a series of tree manipulations in the form of sub-tree rotation (as described in @Quicky's answer).

The algorithm should look like this:

- While node_to_be_root is not the root of the whole tree:

  - Rotate the sub-tree where the node_to_be_root is the pivot and its parent is the root of the sub-tree (after this rotation, the node_to_be_root is going to be the sub-tree's root).

Answer (score 0):

For case 2 you need to perform a tree rotation as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Algorithm i can think of

1. Create a new node with contents same as of the node (which has to be made a new node)
2. Compare new node content with current root node .

   2.1. If it is greater then make the current node as left child of it otherwise right child

   2.2  Also make the other child of current root node as child of new node based on condition 1
3. Delete the other node for which we have made a copy in step 1

**To delete the node here is the algo**

1. Node to be deleted is leaf: Simply remove from the tree.
2. Node to be deleted has only one child: Copy the child to the node and delete the child
3. Node to be deleted has two children: Find inorder(here it means finding last left child of right child of to be deleted node) successor of the node. Copy contents of the inorder successor to the to be deleted node and then ultimately delete the last left child..

Deleting the node is better explained at http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/